# C++ Creating an instance of a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, instance, default-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)
>   [Instantiate class with or without parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490349/instantiate-class-with-or-without-parentheses)

Program:

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo ( int bar = 1 )
      {
         cout << "bar=" << bar;
      }
};

int main() {

   cout << "0 - ";
   Foo foo_0 ( 0 ) ;
   cout << '\n';

   cout << "1 - ";
   Foo foo_1 ();
   cout << '\n';

   cout << "2 - ";
   Foo foo_4;
   cout << '\n';

   return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
0 - bar=0
1 - 
2 - bar=1
```

Question: why example #1 does not works, while examples #0 and #2 do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Foo foo_1 ();
```

is a function declaration, no object is created. It's a function called `foo_1` that takes no parameters and returns a `Foo` object.

The correct way to construct an object there is

```
Foo foo1;
```

This concept is called C++'s [vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). A short description is that anything that can be treated as a declaration, is.

Comment: thanks! Comprehensive answer as usual!

Comment: btw, exmaple #0 is correct too, right?

Answer (score -2):

foo_1(); in other words it's known as Null Intialize you must know difference between the object creation and value intialization.