# C++11 Difference in Constructors (Braces)

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I am quite new to C++ and have observed, that the following lines of code act differently

```
MyClass c1;
c1.do_work() //works
MyClass c2();
c2.do_work() //compiler error c2228: left side is not a class, structure, or union.
MyClass c3{};
c3.do_work() //works
```

with a header file as

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    void do_work();
};
```

Can you explain me, what the difference between the three ways of creating the object is? And why does the second way produce a compiler error?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/3549027

Comment: Two of them: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization. As for the third, look up the Most Vexing Parse and you'll undoubtedly ind it.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490349/instantiate-class-with-or-without-parentheses

Comment: I have never heard of Most Vexing Parse... Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ways one and three call the default constructor.

```
MyClass c3{};
```

Is a new initialization syntax called [uniform initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn387583.aspx). This is called default brace initialization. However:

```
MyClass c2();
```

Declares a function `c2` which takes no parameters with the return type of `MyClass`.

Comment: For brace initialization some explanations and examples can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/dn387583.aspx

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of why it is interpreted as a function, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

Answer (score 7):

The second version

```
MyClass c2();
```

is a function declaration - see the [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588750/cs-most-vexing-parse-again) and [gotw](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/).

The first case is default initialisation.

The last case, new to C++11, will call the default constructor, if there is one, since even though it looks like an initialiser list `{}`, it's empty.

Comment: Declaration, not definition :-)

Comment: Happens to all of us! ;-) (+1)