# how to set object data members with this c++ with this

Tags: c++

So this question is probably a duplicate but when I search I don't find anything. So in C++ if I have

```
class Foo{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        Foo(int x, int y);
};
```

and

```
Foo(int xIn, int yIn){
    x = xIn;
    y = yIn;
}
```

isn't there a way to do the assignment with `this`? So you don't have to change the name for the variables being passed in?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is:

```
Foo(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

Here `x` and `y` hide the member variables, but you can use `this->x` and `this->y` to access them.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way is to use the initialization list:

```
Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
```

Of course, if for whatever reason you want to access the hidden data members in the body of the constructor, you can use the `this` pointer:

```
Foo(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, the preferred way to do this is

```
class Foo{
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Foo(int x, int y): x{x}, y{y}{}
};
```

Or the traditional way ,

```
class Foo{
    int x;
    int y;
public:

    Foo(int x, int y): x(x), y(y){}
};
```

Comment: what's the difference between using {x} and (x)? And what does the empty {} signify at the end?

Comment: The end {} Is the function body (empty). the differences between {} and () for initialization can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307913/c11-difference-in-constructors-braces

Comment: One more question, I'm using a separate header file which has all my function prototypes along with the .cpp file. So from your examples it looks like I would do `Foo(int x, int y) ... ` in the header, is that correct? Do I then have to do anything in the .cpp file?

Comment: You can implement the constructor in the header file or in the cpp files. Both are fine. But for a very small constructor, you can just put it in the header.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to observe scope rules and also maintain clarity, you can always use the class scope operator while assigning the variables

```
class Foo{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Foo(int x, int y);
};

Foo(int x, int y) {
   Foo::x = x;
   Foo::y = y;
}
```